# Run Angular on linux Nginx with proxy

Tags: angular, nginx, proxy, bad-gateway

i have a angular app to be deployed on linux on nginx server with proxy;
I have build the app with:

> ng build --configuration production --base-href /web/ --deploy-url /web/

the resulting output goes into dist/angbaionsweb.
I then copy the content of angbaionsweb to /var/www/baions/web.
I edited the conf file for nginx according to what i have found on google but the result stays always: 502 Bad Gateway.
I added the add_header X-uri to 'debug' so that i know the location is found.
It looks that the proxy is not working well as I have never launched a service that is looking for port 4200. Must i start a 'angular 'service' or is it started by index.html ?

Can someone tell me what is wrong ? or is there more info needed. If so, what info?

The config file for nginx

> upstream mywebserver {  server 127.0.0.1:4200; }
>
> server {   listen 80;
> listen [::]:80;
>
> server_name my.server.eu;
>
> access_log /var/log/nginx/zammad.access.log;
> error_log  /var/log/nginx/zammad.error.log;
>
> location /.well-known/ {
> root /var/www/html;   }
>
> return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
>
> }
>
> server {
> listen 443 ssl http2;
> listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
>
> server_name my.server.eu;
>
> ssl_certificate /xxx;   ssl_certificate_key /xxx;
>
> #SSL info left out
>
> location = /robots.txt  {
> access_log off; log_not_found off;   }
>
> location = /favicon.ico {
> access_log off; log_not_found off;   }
>
> root /opt/zammad/public;
>
> access_log /var/log/nginx/zammad.access.log;
> error_log /var/log/nginx/zammad.error.log;
>
> client_max_body_size 50M;
>
> location ~  ^/(assets/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico|apple-touch-icon.png) {
> expires max;   }
>
> location  /web {
> root /var/www/baions;
> try_files $uri/index.html $uri $uri/ index.html ;
> proxy_pass       http://mywebserver/;
> proxy_redirect off;
> proxy_http_version 1.1;
> proxy_set_header Upgrade    $http_upgrade;
> proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
> proxy_set_header Host       $host;
> proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
> proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
> proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
>
> ```
>   add_header X-uri "location=web  $uri host $http_host " always;
> ```
>
> }

Comment: A compiled Angular `dist` folder has only static files, with an `index.html` that controls all your Angular application. The `upstream` NGINX directive its designed for load balancer service, it does not "start" a new webserver, that's why you are running into 502 error. It tries to do an proxy_pass to a server that does not exist. Check for serving static files through NGINX: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/

Comment: I understand there is no other server, just static pages, so for deployment on linux server with nginx, proxy_pass is not to be used. just make sure the root is correct so that the index.html is found.